# Save data URI in cookie to retrieve it later

Tags: javascript, cookies, html5-canvas

I'm working with html canvas and creating a data URI to preview an image that the user can build himself. When he hits a preview button, the image gets displayed:

```
$("#show_label").html('<img src='+canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier("png",1,1)+' width="157" height="202">');
```

Works fine. Now I want to save the dataURL in a cookie as I want to restore the image at a later stage on the website or store it in my database later.

```
$.cookie("current_label",canvas.toDataURL());
```

That won't work.
I understand that this is not a no-brainer, although it would make sense to store objects in a cookie as well. I guess I would have to encode the data URI and decode it later. But how? Researching didn't give me any results.
Also, could it be that cookies would become too large then so this is not even something to consider?
Should I store the dataURL in a SQL database instead and just use a cookie to identify the database entry (e.g. via ID)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) objects.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use cookies? Might I suggest using `localStorage`?

Example:

```
localStorage['aVariable'] = 'a Value';
//A week later this will still hold value:
alert(localStorage['aVariable'])
```